# Function that returns an array of integers with 1000 elements containing the values 1 to 1000 in random order

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone do this for me please.

Write a function that returns an array of integers with 1000 elements containing the values 1 to 1000 in random order. No number can be repeated or ommitted.

Here is the hint to solve the above question: use `Random rnd=new Random()` to create a new instance of the random number generator and `rnd.Next(1,1000)` to get a random integer value between 1 and 1000.

Many Thanks.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. So to answer your question. Yes, someone could do this for you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to have your homework done for you, sorry. Show us your effort and we are more than willing to advice you how to do it better, correctly, or whatever.

Comment: "Could someone do this for me please." -- What are you willing to pay?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your examiner is probably looking for a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), so the following answer is probably too concise.

```
Random r = new Random();
public int[] GetArr()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).OrderBy(_ => r.Next()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing a cool solution. -1 for not teaching him how to do it himself or even providing an explanation. He will now need to ask about his next homework question, too.

Answer (score -1):

did you try : 
-generate a random number
-check if he is allready in the tab
-put it in your array,in first free position

the only problem will be that it will drastycally slow down on the end

Comment: -1: It won't slow down when using the correct collection type

Comment: The correct way is to populate an array with 1 to 1000, and then "randomly" switch around the elements in the array.

Comment: what will be slowing down is not the search itself, but the fact at the end, you will have to generate the number multiple times before not falling on one who is allready in the tab

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try something where you create a class which contains an int and a bool, the bool can be "isused", then the int can be the index, then use a random number generator, get the number associated with the output, then check if that number is in use by an array of your class, if not then push it onto a list of ints, then once completed return the list as an array?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html

Comment: This will inevitably return an array containing the numbers 1 to 1000 in as random as possible a way, simply using the Random.Next() method. It may not get him an A*, and his fellow students may will be making a field trip to A&E for their split sides, but this method does do exactly what he asked for.